# Dafny - "Verification Inconclusive" on rise4fun

Tags: graph-algorithm, formal-verification, dafny

I got a "Verification Inconclusive" error for a graph algorithm I am trying to prove in the VS2015 dafny mode. I tried using version 2.1.1, the newest version available on the dafny releases page. There's only been one other question about this error on here, and in that case it was a bug in the IDE dafny mode and verified on rise4fun. In this case, the VS2015 dafny mode throws me a "Verification Inconclusive" error, whereas on rise4fun the verifier simply stops working. The code can be found at https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/nhwE, for context. The offending loop invariant is found at line 251, specifically:

```
invariant forall d | d !in e && d in G.edges :: G.d[d.dest] <= old(G.d[d.dest])
```

if this is commented out, the verifier simply works as normal and throws me a "postcondition doesn't hold". What does it mean in this case to get the "Verification Inconclusive" error?

Comment: It probably means there's a bug in Dafny. I tried your code on my machine using the most up-to-date development version (branch master on github) and got no such error. So it looks like the bug has already been fixed.

Comment: My guess is that the verifier needs more time the time limit allows.

In Visual Studio, the time limit is set to 10 seconds per method. You can increase this using an attribute like {:timeLimit 20} placed on the method.

On rise4fun, there's a slightly longer time limit, but since rise4fun shares its CPU between all rise4fun users, there is also a hard time limit, which is set to 30 seconds. If you exceed that 30-second limit, the process is terminated, which may result in getting no output at all.